# Multiple condition for phone number field in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I have below code:

```
$('.mobileNumber').keyup(function () {
   var mobile = $(this).val();
   var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;

    if (mobile.length == 0 || mobile.length < 10 || !mobile.match(numericExpression)) {

     $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.jp-error-msg-kstm').css('display','block');

 } else {

     $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.jp-error-msg-kstm').css('display','none');
   }
});
```

what i'm trying to do is whenever my mobileNumber fields blank(ie. o length),less than 10 length and it should follow numbers only. if yes, then error message i.e. `.jp-error-msg-kstm` will appear else not. 
for example, if i entered 1234567890 then it should not show me the error whereas if erase the value and make the field as 0 length or less than 10 then it should shoe the error span div.

Comment: What is the problem you're encountering?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used

> `mobile.length == 0` 
>   in the first if condition only.

So the code become

```
    $('.mobileNumber').keyup(function () {
        var mobile = $(this).val();
        var numericExpression = /^[0-9]+$/;

        if (mobile.length < 10 || !mobile.match(numericExpression)) {

          if(mobile.length == 0){
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.jp-error-msg-kstm').css('display','none');
          } else {
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.jp-error-msg-kstm').css('display','block');
          }
      } else {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.jp-error-msg-kstm').css('display','none');
       }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `.length`.

```
if (mobile.length < 10 || !mobile.match(numericExpression)) {
```

Comment: Sorry i have used it but forgot to mention here. it still not working.